# Invalid use of member in QSystemDeviceInfo

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

In my code I do

```
#include <QSystemDeviceInfo>

QSystemDeviceInfo devInfo;
if (devInfo.productName != "RM-680") { /* do something */}
```

While building I get an error:

```
error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In C++ '&' means pass by reference, which likely you may be working with pointers rather than an instance of QSystemDeviceInfo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`productName` is a member *function*. You need to call it.

```
if (devInfo.productName() != "RM-680")
```